# How can I make my horizontal navigation bar a drop down menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I've tried making horizontal drop down navigation bars following tutorials, however they are never centered and I can't figure out how to center them. I tried going in the opposite direction and centering my navigation bar first, and then attempting to make it a drop down menu, though this seems to throw everything off. This is the code I have.

EDIT: The problem I am having is that the submenu is displayed when the page is loaded, along with a bullet point, which I'm sure can be fixed by setting the list-style to none, however I'm not sure where in the CSS this should be.

I'm trying to create a menu similar to [THIS](http://www.yootheme.com/demo/wordpress/subway). I understand this uses joomla and I am not.

```css
#header {
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#content {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
#footer {
  height: 85px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1 solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1 solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1 solid #ccc;
}
#menu li {
  float: left;
}
#menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#menu li a:hover {
  color: #c00;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Kandi</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Claim Kandi</a>
      </li>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Events</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Artists</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Community</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Merchandise</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: You have an error in your HTML - at least what you've displayed here. You've opened 2 <ul>'s but you've only closed one. That's an issue.

Comment: Thanks.. fixed. However, the submenu is still displayed when the page is loaded.

Comment: Can you fix the HTML you have displayed in your question so it is the same as what you have on your site? That way we at least know that what you've got is valid HTML before moving on to the CSS...

Answer (score 10):

Add this CSS:

```
#menu, #menu ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}
#menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#menu > li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
#menu li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tcKvH/1/

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
#menu{
position:absolute;
top:150px;
left:8%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#menu ul{
padding:0;
margin:0;
line-height:30px;
}
#menu li{
position:relative;
float:left;
list-style:none;
background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
border-radius:5px;
}
#menu ul ul{
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
padding:0;
margin:0;
top:30px;
}
#menu ul li a{
text-align:center;
font:"Arial Black", Arial;
font-size:24px;
color:rgba(255,255,255,9);
width:150px;
height:30px;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
}
#menu ul li:hover{
background-color:rgba(128,128,128,1);
text-decoration:none;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul{
visibility:visible;
z-index:1;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul li a{
background:rgba(0,0,0,9);
z-index:1;
border-bottom:1px solid rgba(160,160,164,1);
opacity:0.9;
text-decoration:none;
border-radius:5px;
}
#menu ul li ul li:hover{
background:rgba(128,128,128,1);
opacity:0.8;
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

with this html code

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Video</a>    <!--This is in main menu-->
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>   <!--This is in drop downmenu-->
<li><a href="#">Tutorial</a></li>    <!--This is in drop downmenu-->
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```