# Navigation Bar CSS

Tags: css, layout, nav

I want a layout like this:

[image]

So far, I've only tried

```
ul{
    background-color:#e74c3c;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 50px; 
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

But it only covers the the right part. I want a nav bar that's huge and spreads out through the whole page. How do I do this?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666290/how-can-i-make-my-horizontal-navigation-bar-a-drop-down-menu

Comment: use `width:100%` for `ul` and all it's parents, I guess.

Comment: Please create jsFiddle for this..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/4bz2j/ just quick work for you